# Branch On Equal In Assembly/Machine Code

Tags: assembly, branch, mips, machine-code

What is the difference between using:

```
c.eq.s    $1, $2
bc1t      L2
```

And using:

```
beq $1, $2, L2
```

Why are there two ways to branch if they do the same thing? And if they are different, what's the benefit of each?

Thanks

EDIT: I wasn't aware "c.eq.s" is coprocessor specific. I only wrote $1, $2 instead of $f1, $f2, for uniformity with the second set of code.

Comment: @Mysticial I think it should be register-register (or load-store) architecture for the RISC processor

Comment: I mean like, what processor ISA? It's clearly not x86. PowerPC? Sparc? MIPS? ARM? I'm only really familiar with x86. But adding the appropriate tag will bring in the right people to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bc1t` instruction simply branches if math co-processor condition bit 1 is true. That is the case here if the two registers were equal. It's equivalent to simply branching if the values are equal, with `beq`, but *only* if the registers were in fact the same registers in both cases.

With the MIPS floatiing point co-processor, the registers should be `$f1/$f2` in the `c.eq.s` instruction so the two instructions would not be equivalent. I have *never* seen the use of `$1/$2` in floating point instructions, other than in those that move data between the regular registers and the co-processor ones.

I think the *only* way to floating point conditional branches in in a two-step manner. The `IDT MIPS Microprocessor Family Software Reference Manual` states:

> The FP test and branch instructions are separate. A test instruction
>   compares two FP values and set the FPA condition bit accordingly (C in the
>   FP status register); the branch instructions branch on whether the bit is
>   set or unset.

Comment: Does `bc1t` only work where there are coprocessors? For example, working with double precision floating-point numbers, while `beq` work on everything?

Comment: @Synia, I have no idea what bc1t will do if you have no co-processor, it simply checks the value of the special D flip/flop between the CPU and copro. If the copro isn't there, I suspect all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer. I just want to double check I understood it properly. Do you mean that with the MIPS Microprocessor, the two step code is the only way to branch in floating point instructions. It also only works with floating point instructions and nothing else? While using `beq` works with CPU registers and does NOT work with floating point coprocessors?

Comment: @Synia: put it simply, `c.eq.s $f1, $f2` is a floating point comparison (on floating point coprocessor registers), while `beq $1, $2` is an integer comparison (on general purpose registers). In particular, floating point comparison takes care of appropriate treatment on NaNs and INFs.

Comment: @Synia: note there is also a `c.ueq.s` instruction, which treats NaNs differently than `c.eq.s`.